# PHP and SQL INSERT JOIN 2 tables with criteria error

Tags: php, mysql

```
$rentingsquery = "SELECT * FROM TBL_rentings WHERE personId='$personId'
JOIN TBL_rentings ON TBL_properties.propertyId = TBL_rentings.propertyId
JOIN TBL_people ON TBL_rentings.personId = TBL_people.personId";
$rentingsResult=mysql_query($rentingsquery) or die ("Query to get data from TBL_properties failed: ".mysql_error());
```

This is the error I get when I execute the code in my web page:

[image]

What I'm trying to do is select only the 'rentings' where the `personId = $personId`, (as the current page is a page for each individual person), and display only those 'rentings'. Also in the code which I haven't posted I'm displaying data about the property which is related to that rent, hence why I'm trying to join the renting and properties table with propertyId so that I call the correct property's details off the database.

Comment: Please never use screenshots of text, especially when they are error descriptions. People google for these and using images drastically hinders findability, making this question not usable for a broader audience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$rentingsquery = "SELECT * FROM TBL_rentings
    JOIN TBL_rentings ON TBL_properties.propertyId = TBL_rentings.propertyId
    JOIN TBL_people ON TBL_rentings.personId = TBL_people.personId
    WHERE personId='$personId'";
    $rentingsResult=mysql_query($rentingsquery) or die ("Query to get data from TBL_properties failed: ".mysql_error());
```

First of all try this, the where condition has to be after the joins.
If there are other problems I will edit the answer

The next problem is that you are joining the same table, but you are joining it in an external field. A quick fix, if I am supposing correct, is that you wrongly joined with an unwanted table:

```
SELECT * FROM TBL_rentings
JOIN TBL_properties ON TBL_properties.propertyId = TBL_rentings.propertyId
JOIN TBL_people ON TBL_rentings.personId = TBL_people.personId
WHERE TBL_rentings.personId='$personId'
```

Comment: I am sorry, I cannot edit the answer, because there is something weird in the code, you are joining `rentings` with `rentings` ON a field from properties and one from rentings. Shouldn't the table in join be `TBL_properties` ?

Comment: Changing the code to: JOIN TBL_properties ON TBL_rentings.propertyId = TBL_properties.propertyId gives this error; http://puu.sh/lUbCs.png

Comment: You should specify what personId in the where clause. another update to my answer coming.

Comment: I don't know how your tables are structured, it should work, can you please **paste** (not screenshot) the actual code you are using, the table structure and the error?

Comment: YES that fixed it!! Thanks a bunch!